# Cannot publish app via github pages using webpack, why?

Tags: javascript, webpack, github-pages

I'm building a simple application using Tailwindcss, JavaScript & Webpack and trying to publish it via Github Pages.

While running the app via local host works fine, I am encountering a problem when trying to publish the app via gh-pages. I'm receiving the error message "404 File not found", why is that? Are there any dependencies missing in the webpack.config.js or package-json file?

Any help is appreciated.

Please also see github repo: https://github.com/e-d-i/shoppingCart

**package.json**

````
  "name": "shopping-cart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple shopping cart using HTML, CSS / Tailwind CSS, JavaScript & Webpack",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.3.0",
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "postcss": "^8.3.9",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.16",
    "webpack": "^5.56.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  },
  "homepage": "https://e-d-i.github.io/shoppingCart/",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "e-d-i",
  "license": "ISC"
}```


**postcss.config.js**

```const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    tailwindcss
  ],
};```


**webpack.config.js**

```const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./src/script.js",
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname,"./build")
  },
  plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "styles.css",
  })],
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
          test:/\.css$/,
          use:[
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "postcss-loader"
        ]
        }
    ]
  }
}```
````

Comment: I added the index.html file along two other html files in the build folder, resulting in not receiving the 404 error message anymore. Instead the Tailwindcss styles and JavaScript code somehow won't apply...

Comment: In the end I've rebuilt the web app with Parcel and it's finally working now...

Answer (score 0):

You should add a "predeploy" in your package.json like so:

```
"predeploy": "npm run build"
```

and run it locally before you deploy to github pages.

source: https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f